# Scala Error: trait exists, but it has no companion object

Tags: scala, import, traits

I have a situation similar to the following:

```
package A

trait A1{
 def a2 = 0
}

package B

trait B1{
 def b2 = {
  import A.A1._ // Error: trait A1 exists, but it has no companion object
  a2
 }
}
```

This may not be good design, but will be changed in the future. Is there a way to get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import from trait definition. But can import from the instance of the trait definition. `A1` is trait

## Problem

```
import A.A1._
```

The above statement is not valid. When `A.A1._` is imported, Scala compiler is looking for the object `A1` but `A1` is trait, no `A1` is available. So it complains `A1` trait has no companion object.

> Companion object is the object with the same name as class/trait definition

If you want to import trait `A1` (trait definition) into scope. Just do

```
import A.A1
```

You can import the internals of object/companion object

```
object Bar {      
  val x = 1    
}

import Bar._
```

Now `x` is available in scope

If `Foo` is the object then `import Foo._` is valid

## Scala REPL

```
scala> trait A { val a = 1}
defined trait A

scala> val foo = new A{}
foo: A = $anon$1@9efcd90

scala> import foo._
import foo._

scala> a
res0: Int = 1
```

Comment: so basically what you say is that it is not possible to import the definitions in a trait?

Comment: You can from instance of trait but not trait defiNition itself.

Comment: what does `trait A1{ def a2 = 0 }` even mean? it means "instances of trait `A1` have a method `a2`, which returns `0` unless overridden". So pamu's answer is inherent in the meaning of the code you wrote. If this meaning isn't the meaning you intended, you should write something different.

Comment: wait.. a `Trait` can be instantiated?

Comment: I mean you are actually creating anonymous subtype when you do `new A{}`, given `trait A`